# Преобразование строки в объект

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

У меня есть программа клиент-сервер. Я использую `ObjectInputStream` для чтения информации. Программа ждёт сериализованный объект

```java
this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Но при этом мне необходимо, чтобы я мог подключиться через `telnet`, а он отправляет обычную строку.
Я попытался заменить это на

```java
this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Однако возникает проблема несовместимости данных, поскольку `ObjectInputStream` это объект, а он может быть типа `Message`.`BufferedReader`'ом я могу получить строку, но не знаю, как сделать её типом `Message`

```java
Message msgReceived = (Message) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Возможно, я исказил смысл. Поправьте, если это так

Comment: Выдает ошибку при попытке преобразовать ois.readObject() в Message?

Comment: Так в чем проблема получить строку и на основании нее создать объект `Message`?

Comment: может в json слать?